# How to format output in SNMP using Java

Tags: java, snmp

I am trying to send trap messages using SNMP. Used TrapSender and Receiver code from below link,
http://techdive.in/snmp/snmp4j-trap-sender.

```
Output obtained is:
Received PDU...
Trap Type = -89
1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0 = Wed Apr 27 15:17:59 IST 2016
1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.1.0 = 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.6
1.3.6.1.6.3.18.1.3.0 = 127.0.0.1
1.3.6.1.2.1.1.6 = No Exception Occured
```

Now I want my code to generate output in below format, This format is obtained when we use snmpwalk. But I donno how to obtain this format using JAva

```
"1.3.6.1.2.1.1.6.1.1.1.1" 
"1.3.6.1.2.1.1.6.1.1.1.1" 
"1.3.6.1.2.1.1.6.1.1.2.2" s "sdsda" 
"1.3.6.1.2.1.1.6.1.1.2.1" s "2016-04-22 09:36:52"
```

Is this possible? What appproach should I foloow to achieve this? Any help would be appreciated.

### Below is my code for sender:

```
TransportMapping transport = new DefaultUdpTransportMapping();
            transport.listen();

            //Create Target 
            CommunityTarget comtarget = new CommunityTarget();
            comtarget.setCommunity(new OctetString(community));
            comtarget.setVersion(SnmpConstants.version2c);
            comtarget.setAddress(new UdpAddress(ipAddress + "/" + port));
            comtarget.setRetries(2);
            comtarget.setTimeout(5000);

            //Create PDU for V2
            PDU pdu = new PDU();

            // need to specify the system up time
            pdu.add(new VariableBinding(SnmpConstants.sysUpTime, new OctetString(new Date().toString())));
            pdu.add(new VariableBinding(SnmpConstants.snmpTrapOID, new OID(trapOid)));
            pdu.add(new VariableBinding(SnmpConstants.snmpTrapAddress, new IpAddress(ipAddress)));

            // variable binding for Enterprise Specific objects, Severity (should be defined in MIB file)
            pdu.add(new VariableBinding(new OID(trapOid), new OctetString(message))); 
            pdu.setType(PDU.NOTIFICATION);

            //Send the PDU
            Snmp snmp = new Snmp(transport);
            System.out.println("Sending V2 Trap to " + ipAddress + " on Port " + port);
            /*System.out.println("PDU:" + pdu.toString());*/
            snmp.send(pdu, comtarget);
            snmp.close();
```

### Main class:

```
    public class Main{
        public static final String  community  = "public";
        // Sending Trap for sysLocation of RFC1213
        public static final String  trapOid          = ".1.3.6.1.2.1.1.6";                         
        public static final String  ipAddress      = "127.0.0.1";
        public static final int     port      = 162;

        public static void main(String args[]) throws SNMPNullFieldException{  
            TrapSender sender= new TrapSender(community, trapOid, ipAddress, port);
            String message = "No Exception Occured";
sender.sendSnmpV2Trap(message); 
    }  
}
```

Comment: **Of course** it is possible to format output, from any input system. You haven't shown us what you've tried or where it fails.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have added my code, In the receiver  List vbs = pdu.getVariableBindings();
      for(int i=0; i< vbs.size(); i++){
       System.out.println(vbs.get(i));
      } I am doing this, to get the above output, Can u please tel what should I do to get the above format?